# Angular autocomplete search

Tags: html, angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

I have a dropdown where I get some json data. I am doing this in angular. So here I have a List named options where the data is in json format inside. So I have to display the name field at dropdown So my task here is to do a autocomplete search on this dropdown. I have attached my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4t28qi?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html) link here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your filter method as:

```
  private _filter(value: any): any {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }
```

Here is the [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4t28qi-n6ayyj?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts)

Comment: I am having a error. "_filter is declared but its value is never read"

Comment: @JoeRishwanth: it is being used in `ngOnInit` `map(value => this._filter(value))` . help me with this error on stackblitz. I dont see it.

Comment: @JoeRishwanth: would you mind marking it as an answer if it worked

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an object with the filter value.

Your filter callback function should be like this.

```
option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
```

Comment: It isnt working I guess. Can u post the updated or working stackblitz link here?

Comment: Because the stackblitz link isnt showing any dropdown nor search feature

Answer (score 0):

It's solved your problem.

```
 return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
```

Comment: @JoeRishwanth write above code instead of your 'option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)'  code in autocomplete-filter-example.ts file